# C4716 Error - Must Return a Value

Tags: c++

I'm not sure why my program can't run. It is saying User::receiveMessage and User::sendMessage must return a value. I apologize, I am fairly new to programming.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
class User {
public:
  char username[16];
  char userMotto[64];

public:
  User(char name[16], char motto[64]) {
    strcpy(username, name);
    strcpy(userMotto, motto);
  }

  int sendMessage(const char *messageString, User &otherUser) {
    cout << "\n" << username << " is sending this message: " << messageString;
    otherUser.receiveMessage(messageString);
  }

  int receiveMessage(const char *messageString) {
    cout << endl << username << " received this message: " << messageString;
  }
};

int main() {
  User sender("Bill", "I message, therefore I am");
  char message[64];
  cout << "Enter your Message to Send: ";
  cin >> message;
  User receiver("Ted", "I message, therefore I am");
  sender.sendMessage(message, receiver);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Error message is pretty self-explanatory. Your `sendMessage` and `receiveMessage` functions has `int` return type, but you are not returning anything from them. Add `return(0)` to them, or change function signature.

Comment: What do you mean by add return(0) to them? So should I be adding return 0; to the end of the User method?

Comment: `return (0);` is incorrect. It's `return 0;`.

Answer (score 4):

I passed your code through clang-format and [an online Clang compiler](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/4L5voz2N7tBQcrbY) and these are the error messages:

```
prog.cc:20:3: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
  }
  ^

prog.cc:24:3: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
  }
  ^

prog.cc:28:15: warning: ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *' [-Wwritable-strings]
  User sender("Bill", "I message, therefore I am");
              ^

prog.cc:28:23: warning: ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *' [-Wwritable-strings]
  User sender("Bill", "I message, therefore I am");
                      ^

prog.cc:32:17: warning: ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *' [-Wwritable-strings]
  User receiver("Ted", "I message, therefore I am");
                ^

prog.cc:32:24: warning: ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *' [-Wwritable-strings]
  User receiver("Ted", "I message, therefore I am");
                       ^
```

To fix the first two warnings, you'll need to change those functions:

```
  int receiveMessage(const char *messageString) {
    cout << endl << username << " received this message: " << messageString;
  }
```

Does `receiveMessage` need to return an `int`? If not, change it to a `void` return type:

```
void receiveMessage(...
```

If it does need to return an `int`, add a `return` statement at the end:

```
  int receiveMessage(const char *messageString) {
    ...
    return 0;
  }
```

For the other warnings you could replace the `char[]` with `std::string` throughout, but they're not so bad.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error and it is so easy to miss in Visual Studio!

It simply means that a method does not return anything even though you have specified it:

```
int method() {
    // you should return here sth
}
```